# 100% height for bootstrap columns in container

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row with 3 columns nested within a container which I'd like to give a height of 100% for each row, applying vertical scrolling if they overflow.

#### Current Layout

[image: Current layout]

#### DOM

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav...

        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="content" ui-view>
                <!-- content starts here (loaded by angular)-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <!-- example column content -->
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="..."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- content ends here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
```

I tried a lot of things now, e.g. *negative margins*, *absolute* positioning, displaying the columns as *table/table-cells*. However everytime the content populates, the *list groups* expand to the height they need for displaying all items, pushing the whole site down.

Based on other examples, it should work this way (it does not, though -> has no effect):

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.table-row { // applied to "row"
    display: table;

    > [class*="col-"] { // applied to columns
        vertical-align: top;
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
    }
}

.overflow-auto { // applied to the list groups inside the columns
    height: 100% !important;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Anyone got an idea about how to solve this?

#### Examples tried:

- [How to make bootstrap column height to 100% row height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213171/how-to-make-bootstrap-column-height-to-100-row-height)
- [Twitter bootstrap 3 two columns full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height)
- [Setting 100% height to columns in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920972/setting-100-height-to-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap)
- [Bootstrap 3 - 100% height of custom div inside column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773342/bootstrap-3-100-height-of-custom-div-inside-column)
- http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: Have you tried `max-height:` css style?

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze For what? The list groups? The row? Each column?

Comment: Try adding a max-height to your div class content.

Comment: I didnt read your question throughly sorry.  Check my jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/366eynsL/1/
I would wrap the content you want verticle scroll for with a div and add `overflow-y: scroll;` and a `height:` css style.

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze Yes, that's more or less what I'm doing, however upon content population, the div gets pushed down over it's allowed height.